# <script type="text/javascript">

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between

`<script type="text/javascript">`

and

`<script>`

tags ?

Comment: reformatted tags, now it makes more sense :)

Answer (score 3):

The `type` attribute is no longer a required attribute in most browsers.

From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script):

> type
>
> This attribute identifies the
>   scripting language of code embedded
>   within a script element or referenced
>   via the element’s src attribute. This
>   is specified as a MIME type; examples
>   of supported MIME types include
>   text/javascript, text/ecmascript,
>   application/javascript, and
>   application/ecmascript. **If this
>   attribute is absent, the script is
>   treated as JavaScript.**

Comment: The `type` attribute is still very much required if you want your pages to validate and use either HTML 4 or XHTML 1, which are the only viable standards on the web at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between those two tags. Prior to HTML5 you need to explicitly add 'text/javascript'. On HTML5 you can skip that part.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will default type to `text/javascript`, but other values are allowed, see

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

Also, as for [W3C specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2)

> As HTML does not rely on a specific scripting language, document authors must explicitly tell user agents the language of each script. This may be done either through a default declaration or a local declaration.

Comment: I didn't -1, but the trend on stackoverflow is that anytime someone links w3schools.com, they get a -1.

Comment: @Error 454: I really hope that was not the reason for the -1. There is nothing wrong in that w3schools page and downvoting a correct answer for that would be just dumb. Especially because I did also link to the W3C specifications...

Answer (score 0):

As per [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html) standard its essential. As HTML does not rely on a specific scripting language, document authors must explicitly tell user agents the language of each script. This may be done either through a default declaration or a local declaration.

Comment: This is true of XHTML but not HTML5: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-script-type

Answer (score 0):

According to [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/15276-the-script-tag/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //some javascript here
</script>
```

> The type attribute is the standard and correct way to identify and
>   tell the browser what kind of script the tag contains. Sometimes
>   you'll see code that uses both the language and type attribute. As far
>   as I know that's never necessary.
>
> Really specific explanation from the spec, language is an "obsolete
>   but conforming" feature.

but

```
<script>
  //some javascript here
</script>
```

> No attributes at all. This is the HTML5 way of handling script tags
>   that contain JavaScript. It's just assumed that the type is
>   text/javascript. If it's not (I've never even seen a different type of
>   script) you'll need to change it with the type attribute. I recommend
>   this is you are using HTML5.